# Cytoscape.js how to save image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cytoscape.js

Does anyone who happens to know how to save image of our graph? I know someone tried to use cy.png(), but I don't know the detail how to use it. Any ideas? Thanks
Problem above solved! but I have new problem below:

I still have problem to remove the background color (grey) which is not in the browser.
it seems mac has the background color (grey) problem, while windows is fine. aside from this problem, Anyone who has any idea to get a high resolution image?

Comment: I already known how to save it as png now, but I still have problem to remove the background color (grey) which is not in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a ticket for the issue you described:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/365

Comment: Hi Max, can you tell me how you saved your image without grey background? It turns out I have no problem with windows but grey background with mac (preview software used), thanks.

Comment: If the background is transparent in the image, of course you'll see the grey background of Preview through the image.